# Create a topic on Code Review for a question put on hold

Tags: discussion, on-hold, code-review-se

Today, the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393112/find-out-if-string-contains-english-words-only) got put on hold. However, the question intrigued me and I thought the question through a bit longer, and then prototyped an answer in a different language, just for the sake of testing the algorithm.

As I thought the original author might benefit from this sample, and because I was a curious how others might see the algorithm, I posted the code on Code Review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140886/making-sure-a-sentence-exists-of-words-in-a-dictionary)

As I didn't want to do this "behind the back" of the original author, I posted a comment on the original topic with a link to the topic on code review.

Now maybe this might be too broad to answer, but is this an approach which is okay according to the community, or should I have just posted to Code Review without linking the two together?

Comment: this isn't really relevant for the SO meta. Overall you're welcome to use content on the SE network under the CC-BY-SA license. Making a codereview post with that doesn't seem really far off, does it? Code Review even has the tag [tag:rags-to-riches], which is for questions that do exactly what you did. I went ahead and tagged the question on Code Review...

Comment: @Vogel612 Thanks for the info :) So I should rather close this question then?

Comment: Do note that there is a [Code Review Meta site](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/), where it probably would have been more appropriate to ask this question. We can tell you whether you violated any licensing or attribution rules global to the Stack Exchange network (you haven't), but we really can't tell you any details about the acceptability of your question on Code Review.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok, I mainly wanted to know if I violated any rules, not really if the question was acceptable for codereview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't break any rules. I've actually done the reverse: CR to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37094007/6083675).

---

User contributions on the Stack Exchange network are licensed under [cc by-sa](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). In order for you to "share" or "adapt" the content, you must meet these two points:

> - Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.
> - ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.

There is no requirement to alert the original source, since this could be an impossible task if you're citing an academic paper.

Whether you do leave a comment or not is up to you really: is it likely to be perceived as helpful or interesting or is it likely to be perceived as self-promotion or noise?

Code Review obviously uses the same license as Stack Overflow and there's technically a link to the license already at the bottom of each page: "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required". You should be fine on these two points. You are fine as long as you have some sort of introduction that gives attribution and indicates that you made changes (asking for reviews on others' code is strictly off-topic anyway).

You seem to be fine, but if you forgot attribution you could just edit it in.

---

I'm not sure if your question should use the [Rags to Riches tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/rags-to-riches/info), since the [meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2039/104611) says:

> I suggest we take on the challenge of finding the worst code out there on our sister sites, and making it the best!

You took an algorithm, not code.